# :hover pseudo-class of CSS does not work in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I have problem with the `:hover` pseudo-class of CSS.

I am using it like

```
tr.lightRow:hover {
    color:red
}
```

It works in Safari and Firefox but it does not work in IE7. Please help me.

Comment: you may want to post some example code

Comment: What are you applying `:hover` to?

Comment: `:hover` is a pseudo-class and not a property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE7 supports :hover, at least in standards mode. It may not in quirks mode.

Comment: how can i activate the standards mode

Comment: Add a strict !DOCTYPE to your documents to enable full IE7 goodness

Answer (score 4):

IE has a history of bad CSS support. Originally only `a` tags supported `:hover`. And also you couldn't have something like `a:hover span` to indicate that only the `span` tag should change when hovering the parent `a`.

If you want correct `:hover` functionality across all IE versions, you need to use javascript and `onmouseover`/`onmouseout`.

It also helps if you use an xhtml doctype, to enable standards mode.

Answer (score 3):

IE 6 only supports the `:hover` pseudo class on links, but IE 7 supports it on most elements.

As David mentioned, it might not work in quirks mode. The reason would then be that IE mostly reverts back to something closer to IE 4 in quirks mode, allowing a lot of IE specific features and removing several standards compliant features.

If you want the `:hover` functionality on a block element and support back to IE 6, you can use a link element and make it a block element using CSS. Note that a link only can contain inline elements (e.g. no `div`s) so if you want block elements inside the link you would have to set that using CSS also:

CSS:

```
.hoverlink { display: block; }
.hoverlink:hover { background: #eee; }
.hoverlink .item { display: block; }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="..." class="hoverlink">
  <span class="item">Line 1</span>
  <span class="item">Line 2</span>
  <span class="item">Line 3</span>
</a>
```

(You might want to consider the impact on search engines using the technique also. A link has better impact if it just contains the text describing what it links to.)

Answer (score 0):

:hover is not supported by every element e.g. it works on `<a>` but breaks on `<div>` afaik

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this a few times  - have a look at the following link ..

http://www.bernzilla.com/item.php?id=762

"if you want support for :hover on all elements and not just the <a> tag, make sure you're using a strict DOCTYPE so IE7 doesn't kick in to quirks mode."