# Hover not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Can someone help me take a look at this please,

Here is the link to my website:

http://mojogobbles.com.sg/cupcake-menu/

Here is my css coding for the div class and also the html

CSS

```
#f1{
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 left: 370px;
 top: 450px;
 background:black;
 position: absolute;
 opacity:0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 float: left;
 -webkit-transition: 1s all;
 -moz-transition: 1s all;
 transition: 1s all;
 }
#f1:hover {
 background:url(images/flavours/f1.jpg);
 width: 320px;
 height: 320px;
 opacity:100;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div id="f1"></div>
```

The hover does not work for IE!
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: the answer is in your title :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which version of IE... I think < 7 does not support the :hover pseudo-class on any element other than the intended anchor `a` element.

Edit, also this might help for IE7:

[:hover pseudo-class of CSS does not work in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077411/hover-pseudo-class-of-css-does-not-work-in-ie7)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add  [HTML 4.01 Strict DOCTYPE](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.1) on the top of your page to get it work in IE.

This is for `IE`>=7

Comment: For IE transitions consult this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544162/imitate-css3-transition-in-ie