# CSS dropdowns not working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, hover

I have some dropdown menus that work great in everything but IE7, unfortunately my boss runs IE8 in compatibility mode so he wants them fixed... I'm not sure what the issue is:

```
.m-main-nav li ul {
display: none;
top: 24px;
left: -41px;
float: left;
width: 190px;
z-index: 999999;
position: absolute;
background: none;
background-color: none;
opacity: .9;}

.m-main-nav li:hover > ul {display: block;}

.m-main-nav li ul li {
min-width: 180px;
padding: 0;
background-image: none;
text-decoration: none;
border: solid 1px #bfa049;
border-top:0px;
vertical-align: bottom}
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: `my boss runs IE8 in compatibility mode`. For the love of.... why??? Also, what doesn't work? Posting your html would be good too.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: tell your boss that ie7 is the new ie6 and he should switch to something better... like telneting to port 80 and rendering the html himself.

Comment: is your `.m-main-nav li` set to `position: relative`? But seriously, give us a fiddle!

Comment: possible duplicate of [:hover pseudo-class of CSS does not work in IE7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077411/hover-pseudo-class-of-css-does-not-work-in-ie7)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that IE7 is operating in standards mode? Ensure that you have a proper doctype like

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

in your html. Otherwise `:hover` won't work on arbitrary elements, but only on `<A>`.